# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::transform()

Tags: laravel

I am trying to make a query in Laravel, which should select values based on date, pick_score and order by hour and also by some specific String values that I have in my data set. The query is below, but I get "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::transform()" and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
    $matches = Match::select()
    ->where('date', $date)
    ->where('pick_score', '<>', '0')
    ->orderBy('hour')
    ->transform(function ($match) {
        if(
            $match->competition_type == "ATP - SINGLES" 
            or
            $match->competition_type == "WTA - SINGLES"
        ){
            $match->competition_type = -1;
        }else{
            $match->competition_type = 'competition_type';
        }
        return $match;
    })
    ->sortBy('competition_type');
```

Can anyone help me with this error?

Answer (score 1):

The shared method names can get a little confusing, but the gist of it is, running `orderBy()` on a Builder object just returns the same Builder object, *not* a Collection.  To get the Collection you're expecting, tell the Builder to execute the query first by placing a `get()` call between `orderBy()` and `transform()`.

By the way, `Collection::transform()` doesn't return anything.  I think what you want there instead is `map()`.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, I added the "get" and also turned the "Transform" into "map" and now I get this error: "Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(),". I tried to add $match or $matches, but it does not work :( . What should I do ?

Comment: That very confusing.  Calling transform() on the result of orderBy() acts like that result was a Builder object.  But calling get() on it acts like it was a Collection... If someone else doesn't beat me to it later, I'll take a look at this when I'm back in front of a computer.

Comment: For now, maybe just send the output of _each_ method call to a separate variable and do a get_class() on each one for a sanity check on what you're working with there.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $matches = Match::select()
    ->where('date', $date)
    ->where('pick_score', '<>', '0')
    ->orderBy('hour')
    ->get()
    ->transform(function ($match) {
        if(
            $match->competition_type == "ATP - SINGLES" 
            or
            $match->competition_type == "WTA - SINGLES"
        ){
            $match->competition_type = -1;
        }else{
            $match->competition_type = 'competition_type';
        }
        return $match;
    })
    ->sortBy('competition_type');
```

It can solve your problem.

Laravel has eloquent orm library for database queries. https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/eloquent. It has get method which fetch data as a Collection from db. Collection methods are similar with eloquent. So most of the time people confuse them. Transform is a collections method. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-transform